# Python Turtle issue drawing based on user input

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

My problem is that my height of the tower variable is not printing at all, and I feel if it did it would not work. I cannot understand why this isn't working please help.

My Code:

```
import turtle
bob = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.setup(width = 400, height = 300)
turtle.bgcolor("orange")
n = int(input("Please enter number of towers: "))
h = (input("Please enter height of towers : "))
x = str(h.split(","))
def ocean():
    bob.setpos(-200, 0)
    bob.color("midnightblue", "midnightblue")
    bob.begin_fill()
    for x in range(1, 3):
        bob.forward(400)
        bob.right(90)
        bob.forward(150)
        bob.right(90)
    bob.end_fill()

def tower():
    bob.right(90)
    for x in range (0,n):
        bob.forward(x)


ocean()
tower()
```

Comment: what is yur expected output?

Comment: You never print `h` (or `x`).  That is why it is "_not printing at all_".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that beginning programmers either write *too much* code or *too little* code.  In the case of your `tower()` function, it's *too little* code.  You also use the `x` variable for two different purposes -- get out of the habit of using single letter variable names.  Your "Please enter number of towers: " question isn't needed as the number of tower heights entered gets you that same value.  This is your first logic error:

```
x = str(h.split(","))
```

We do want to split that input string on comma, but we want to turn it into a list of number instead of strings.  One way:

```
x = map(int, h.split(","))
```

The next issue surfaces in `tower()`:

```
for x in range (0,n):
    bob.forward(x)
```

This reuse of `x` masks our heights, what you really wanted was something like:

```
for idx in range(n):
    bob.forward(x[idx])
    ...
```

But we don't need to use indexing, we can simply *walk* `x` itself.  A rework of your code with the above fixes, some tower drawing, and some style changes:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 400, 300

def ocean():
    bob.setpos(-WIDTH/2, 0)
    bob.color("midnightblue")
    bob.begin_fill()

    for _ in range(2):
        bob.forward(WIDTH)
        bob.right(90)
        bob.forward(HEIGHT/2)
        bob.right(90)

    bob.end_fill()

def tower():
    for height in heights:
        bob.left(90)
        bob.forward(height)
        bob.right(90)
        bob.forward(50)
        bob.right(90)
        bob.forward(height)
        bob.left(90)

heights_string = input("Please enter height of towers: ")
heights = map(int, heights_string.split(","))

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
screen.bgcolor("orange")

bob = Turtle()

ocean()
tower()

bob.hideturtle()

screen.mainloop()
```

**USAGE**

```
> python3 test.py
Please enter height of towers: 100,30,140,60,90,20,45
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: cdlane thankyou so much, you have helped so much and thankyou for explaining the issue in detail. :)